# How faithful is "American Sniper" to the book?

Tags: book-adaptation, historical-accuracy, american-sniper

I loved American Sniper, but one thing that bugged me was that his spotter was always depicted as a lazy do-nothing. In the real world, snipers work as a two man team and the spotter is just as important as the shooter.

I did not read the book, so I am wondering whether Kyle depicts himself in the book shooting solo and doing his own spotting while his spotter sat around doing nothing OR did the film-makers deliberately change that to emphasize the "heroic" aspect? In other words, did the film-makers not want to show a real spotter because they thought that would take away from the main character and make him seem less heroic if he was just half of a two-man team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seal team snipers dont operate with a spotter. Kyle states this in his book.

Comment: Hi.  This may be true, but is this the only difference?